# How To Set CheckBoxFor Values Correctly Based On ViewModel Change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My view model contains list of items. The list items are displayed by `@Html.CheckBoxFor` for user interaction. Initial set-up (i.e. checking values last selected in previous session) as well as manual selection and de-selection work correctly and bind back to the view model.

Function "Uncheck All" was added to the page recently. **It sets each list item value `IsSelected` to false, but all items remains unchanged on the page.**

When checking the `ModelState.Values`, the `AttemptedValue` of corresponding items got changed to "true\false" instead of "false". **Am I missing any binding operation?**

Quick summary of the main code parts:

View Model:

```
public class RuleDetail
{
  public List<DataSourceCheckList> dataSourceCheckList { get; set; }
  // many other items, methods etc...
}
```

View code:

```
@for (int n = 0; n < Model.dataSourceCheckList.Count; n++)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dataSourceCheckList[n].DataSourceName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.dataSourceCheckList[n].DataSourceName)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.dataSourceCheckList[n].IsSelected)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.dataSourceCheckList[n].DataSourceId)
}
```

The class from the list:

```
public class DataSourceCheckList
{
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public string DataSourceName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int columnCount = 0; //captures DataSetColumns count (0 migt mean the data source haven't been audited)
}
```

And the Post controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Builder(int? id, ViewModels.RuleDetail rd, string ignoreChecklists, string command, int? callerId, string callerController, string callerAction)
    {
        //some other logic...
        switch (command)
        {
            //bunch of other command values

            case "UnselectSources":
                foreach (DataSourceCheckList i in rd.dataSourceCheckList)
                {
                    i.IsSelected = false;
                }
                break;
         }

        //update of other view model fields based on actions above

        return View(rd);
     }
```

Please, do you see any options, how to ensure the values in `RuleDetail.dataSourceCheckList` are displayed correctly?

Comment: After getting no traction on this issue, I've used a java script to uncheck items in the view and submit form to controller to resolve rest of the updates (example here: https://makitweb.com/how-to-check-and-uncheck-all-using-jquery-and-javascript/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was driven by model state. Applying `ModelState.Clear()` to `[HttpPost]` controller action eliminated the true\false state observed before and values updated during the post action (including the checkbox mentioned in the original questions) are displaying correctly now.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Builder(int? id, ViewModels.RuleDetail rd, string ignoreChecklists, string command, int? callerId, string callerController, string callerAction)
{
    //some other logic...
    switch (command)
    {
        //bunch of other command values

        case "UnselectSources":
            foreach (DataSourceCheckList i in rd.dataSourceCheckList)
            {
                i.IsSelected = false;
            }
            break;
     }

    //update of other view model fields based on actions above

    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(rd);
 }
```